# use htaccess file to create a url variable from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to write an htaccess file that takes the input links and coverts them to the output (which is basically anything after the /test/ and adding ?location=

**Input**

1. http://test.co.uk/test/uk/england/london
2. http://test.co.uk/test/uk/england
3. http://test.co.uk/test/uk/england/london/soho

to: **(Output)**

1. http://test.co.uk/test/?location=uk/england/london
2. http://test.co.uk/test/?location=uk/england
3. http://test.co.uk/test/?location=uk/england/london/soho

Comment: Please check the "Related" sidebar. There are many tutorials on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your **test** directory, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?location=$1 [L]
```

Or in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/?location=$1 [L]
```

Comment: In the test directory, you might need a `RewriteBase /test/`.